# Is there data.table equivalent of 'select_if' and 'rename_if'?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

Suppose I have a data frame like this.

```
df <- data.frame(w = runif(2), x = c(T, F), y = letters[1:2], z = c(1L, 2L))
```

With dplyr, I can easily rename / select based on the class of columns or by any other function that returns logical. For example, I can do

```
df %>% select_if(is.logical)
%       x
% 1  TRUE
% 2 FALSE

df %>% rename_if(is.double, paste, 'hat', sep = '_')
%       w_hat     x y z
% 1 0.8619479  TRUE a 1
% 2 0.8750867 FALSE b 2
```

to select 'x' column, or rename 'w' to 'w_hat'.

Is there any data.table equivalent of these function based column selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), loop through the columns, apply the `is.double`, `unlist` and get the column names.  Then, with `setnames` change the column names

```
nm1 <- names(which(setDT(df)[, unlist(lapply(.SD, is.double))]))
setnames(df, nm1, paste0(nm1, "_hat"))
df
#       w_hat     x y z
#1: 0.2925740  TRUE a 1
#2: 0.2248911 FALSE b 2
```

---

It is possible to use the `dplyr` convenient functions in `data.table`

```
setDT(df)[, select_if(.SD, is.logical)]
#      x
#1:  TRUE
#2: FALSE


setDT(df)[, rename_if(.SD, is.double, paste, 'hat', sep="_")]
#       w_hat     x y z
#1: 0.2925740  TRUE a 1
#2: 0.2248911 FALSE b 2
```

Note:  The `rename_if` doesn't change the column names in the original dataset while `setnames` does change it.

Comment: Thanks! Great to know that I can use dplyr functions inside [.

Comment: Similarly using the `mutate_if` inside a data.table is very useful to transform all columns of a specific type . It prevents writing complex code code like (`names(which(setDT(df)[, unlist(lapply(.SD, is.double))]))` ). Thanks